# All animations are not exporting in .glb format?

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I tried creating a ps1 style character in blender by following a tutorial. I created 7 animations in there as you can see below.

[image: Animation list]

But when I reimport the .glb file inside blender, it only shows basic_attack1, basic_attack2, basic_attack3, basic_attack4

I need to export it as .glb file. I am using blender 2.91.0.

Below is my export settings for animation.

[image: Export settings]

heres the file,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blender documentation has a section on how to ensure that your scene can export to glTF. It looks like only some of your actions are marked as NLA tracks, which is probably why not all are exported. See:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html